# Стэк ассемблера

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте, у меня вопрос по стэку, само его устройство мне понятно, не понятно другое:

1. Для каждого процесса выделяется своя область памяти под стэк, или он общий для всех процессов?
2. К стэку не относится, но все же, на счет регистров, процессов много а их 4, может ли получаться там что сторонние процессы будут трогать регистры временно занятые моим процессом?
3. Как вобще организованна многозадачность 80386 процессорах.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: регистров больше

Answer (score 5):

Круто!

1. Да, для каждого процесса стек свой. На 386+ чужие области памяти просто не видны (отображение адресов, virtual 8086)
2. Смотреть на тему "контекст процесса". При переключении регистры сохраняются.
3. Самый маленький вопрос (тем более с учётом SMP для многоядерных процессоров). По-разному. Читайте книги.

Answer (score 3):

1. У каждого потока есть свой стек. Если процесс состоит из нескольких потоков, то у него будет столько же стеков. Если тебе понятно устройство стека, то такого вопроса не должно было возникнуть. Как ты себе представляешь общий стек?
2. Регистры текущего потока сохраняются при переключении потоков и загружаются регистры нового потока.
3. На всех процессорах принцип примерно одинаковый (см. п. 2), но реализация на ассемблере, конечно же, своя, так как у них разные ассемблеры. Конечно надо учитывать возможности процессора, такие, как многодерность, защита памяти и другие.

Comment: Ну самое первое, что приходит в голову: вытесняющая и кооперативная многозадачности. Про многопроцессорную обработку я уж и не говорю.